# InvalidateWindow() stops working

Tags: plugins, firebreath

i am writing a plugin with content to display,
collected code from all examples i found on the internet, i run PluginWindowX11 on Firefox
and everything works as expected, except the plugin stops redrawing after 1-5 minutes of work,

what i do is:

1. set 40ms timer, i wait for this to refresh the display

   m_timer = FB::Timer::getTimer(40, true, boost::bind(&PluginWindowX11::update, this));
   m_timer->start()
2. in the callback i ask the browser for expose event

   void PluginWindowX11::update() {
       InvalidateWindow();
       return;
   }
3. in gboolean PluginWindowX11::EventCallback(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event)
   for the GDK_EXPOSE event i redraw the window

switch(event->type)
{
case GDK_EXPOSE:
        {
            GdkEventExpose * exposeEvent = reinterpret_cast(event);
            FB::Rect rect;
            rect.left = exposeEvent->area.x;
            rect.top = exposeEvent->area.y;
            rect.right = exposeEvent->area.x + exposeEvent->area.width;
            rect.bottom = exposeEvent->area.y + exposeEvent->area.height;
            FBLOG_INFO("EXPOSE", string_format("got expose m_canvas = %X rect: ", m_canvas) << rect_format(rect));
            redrawdraw();
            RefreshEvent evt(rect);
            return SendEvent(&evt) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

i redraw the whole window, no matter what part of it is exposed, i just print it for reference

i have seen it working 10 minutes, usualy after a minute the plugin stops redrawing itself.
i have verified that the timer is running, i calls InvalidateWindow() but there is no more GDK_EXPOSE events, not a single one, everything else is working its printing debug and responding to mouse events, it just wont get new expose event,
i cannot be 100% sure but i did not get WindowDetached events

anyone else experiencing this ?

system is 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 Xfce , testing it on firefox 29.0

thanks in advance

Comment: not a clue. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Kalo who pointed me this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/qlxpThEUHH0

problem fixed when i added all the gdk_thread_init/enter/leave calls